# Apache ActiveMQ Temporary Store limit warning?

Tags: java, apache, tcp, activemq-classic

I have been facing this below WARN in active.log file very often . Don't understand what exactly every warning means . Can some please help me to understand this and how to fix

> 1, 2017-06-07 11:11:12,051 | WARN  | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb
>   (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory:
>   /local/apps/apache-activemq-5.14.3/data only has 5924 mb of usable
>   space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 5924 mb |
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
>
> 2, 2017-06-07 11:36:02,358 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://10.235.454.23:59053 failed: java.io.EOFException |
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ
>   Transport: tcp:///10.123.343.345:59053@61616
>       2017-06-07 11:37:58,441 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://10.123.345.768:46840 failed: java.io.EOFException |
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ
>   Transport: tcp:///10.240.123.234:46840@61616
>
> 3, 2017-06-07 11:41:54,376 | WARN  | persistent="false", ignoring
>   configured persistenceAdapter:
>   KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/local/apps/apache-activemq-5.14.3/data/kahadb]
>   | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this error/warning you should limit the broker's temporary store limit to a value that is available on disk. This value is set in the broker's system usage configuration by the tempUsage limit in apache-activemq-5.9.0-bin\apache-activemq-5.9.0\conf\activemq.xml:

```
<systemUsage>
   <systemUsage>
      <memoryUsage>
          <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
      </memoryUsage>
      <storeUsage>
         <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
      </storeUsage>
      <tempUsage>
         <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
      </tempUsage>
   </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

While the broker may perform ok at first with this condition it has the potential to lead to unexpected results such IOExceptions rather than triggering Producer Flow Control when the resources are exhausted. It is recommend to fix this situation by adjusting the usages limits appropriately.

**Root Cause**

The broker has requested to allocate more disk resources than what is available. 
Please check you disk space memory where activemq is located before setting up the tempusage memory .

ActiveMQ provides mechanism to tune memory usage per destination

```
<policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="256mb">
```

I have used wild card character in queue name [> is used to recursively match any destination starting from this name] in the above configuration it is for any queues
Anyways for each destnation you can use

Per-destination—to set a memory limit on a destination, For example, to limit the amount of memory on the FOO.BAR.TEST queue to 10 MB, define a policy entry like the following:

```
<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic="FOO.BAR.TEST" memoryLimit="5MB" />
        </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

Comment: as you said , my disk space is lesser than defined value . I want to know does the below configuration   :<policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="256mb">  will be applied to individual queue or all queues which is created in broker .

Comment: Have edited on my above post . Please revert incase of any query

Answer (score 1):

I declare the Broker service programatically in spring configuration. I used the xml snippet from Rajesh Katadi's answer as a guide.

```java
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DisposableBean brokerService() throws Exception {
        long limitBytes = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.setBrokerName("my-broker");
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.getSystemUsage().getStoreUsage().setLimit(0L);
        broker.getSystemUsage().getMemoryUsage().setLimit(limitBytes);
        broker.getSystemUsage().getTempUsage().setLimit(limitBytes);
        broker.start();
        broker.waitUntilStarted();
        return () -> {
            broker.stop();
            broker.waitUntilStopped();
        };
    }

    @Bean @DependsOn("brokerService")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://my-broker?broker.persistent=false");
    }
    ...
}
```